# Button debounce using millis() in this example

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have been trying to find a way to use millis() instead of delay(), in order to press 2 buttons to turn on and off a blue led.

EDITED:

```
const int right_button = 8, left_button = 9, yellow_led = 7, blue_led = 6, green_led = 5, red_led = 4;
int previous_left_button_status = LOW, previous_right_button_status = LOW, blue_status = LOW, green_status = LOW;
unsigned long time_setup = millis();
const int delay_task = 250;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(right_button, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(left_button, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(blue_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow_led, OUTPUT);
  Display.clear();
}

void loop()
{
  int right_button_status = digitalRead(right_button);
  int left_button_status = digitalRead(left_button);
  unsigned long time_passes = millis();
  if (time_passes - time_setup >= delay_task)
  {
    time_setup = time_passes;
    if (right_button_status == previous_right_button_status)
    {
      green_status = !green_status;
      digitalWrite(green_led, green_status);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: start with the arduino debounce example sketch ..https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce

Comment: `this code does not work` is a very poor description of the program behavior ... what actually happens when you run the sketch?

Comment: @jstola, my bad for not being specific ;/ my problem here is with both buttons, right/left_button_press are not working as I want them to turn on and off a LED using only delay

Comment: you have logic errors in your code .. . using the `else` keyword creates code that excludes one of the buttons if the other button is pressed ... each button should have a separate `if` statement

Comment: @jstola, so "else if" here means exactly the same as "else",  if a condition is met then do this, and if not(else) do the other one but do not execute the first condition, correct?

Comment: @jstola, why is it considered to be a logical error? what if the scenario that I want excludes one condition and activate the other? or do you mean by error, is that if I press right button to turn on a LED, i cannot turn that LED forever because of `else if` ?

Comment: a logic error is something like adding two numbers, when you meant to multiply ... you are monitoring two button presses, but you are excluding a button press under certain conditons because you think that the button press detection is somehow related to the lighting of an LED .... but, the LED lighting and the button press detection are really completely separate functions ... a button press should set a value of a variable, nothing more .... the resulting value can be used to determine if an LED should be lit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106446/discussion-between-ryan-johnson-and-jsotola).

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the variable for the millis function inside your loop correct and you've declared the delay duration you want to use. Two things you've missed are you've declared 2 variables with the millis function and to use it to control the program flow based on some condition to execute some code, in your case, to press 2 buttons to turn on and off an LED.

The way to to this is to use an if-else statement inside the loop function with one variable declared with the millis function, delay_duration as your reference, and 1 variable declared with a zero value.

```
unsigned long storeMillis = 0;
const int delay_duration = 500;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
if (currentMillis - storeMillis > 500) {
storeMillis = currentMillis; //update and store the value of storeMillis for the next iteration
//code you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did somewhat understand your `millis()`. First, you have an unsigned long which has not been used, you used firstMillis, I think you meant storeMillis in that `if` condition, correct? Second, how do I use that in a button debounce, I still do not understand the button debounce part using millis()

Comment: I suggest that you first change the variables that you used in storing the states of the buttons from true/false to high/low. You've set your variable "left_state" as a boolean wherein you gave it a pin level of "LOW" which is a big no no. Remember that boolean is used in defining logical levels to represent a truth or not while HIGH/LOW is used to represent pin levels in Arduino.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, do you mind taking a look at my edited code? millis() is not working in my EDITED part, I still do not know why my right button is not debouncing (going with the flow, everytime I press it) it misses, waits or not turn a led ON

Comment: Great, now you need to carefully check if you're comparing the right variables in your condition. Remember that the millis() function starts keeping track of time where you declared it in your code. The variable "time_setup"' is the one that will start counting, say 0 to 5000ms, until the loop function starts. Then that will be the time your variable "time_passes" will start counting, therefore the time value of it must be lesser than the time value of "time_setup".

Comment: I suggest that you print these values in the serial monitor for you to know what's actually going on and how it's storing the time in milliseconds.

Comment: i really am confused, first you have a variable called `secondMillis` which was never declared anywhere, and then you did `storeMillis = millis();` why didn't you store `storeMillis to currentMillis` ? ;/

Comment: My bad, I edited it already. I was pertaining to the second variable that I declared when I was writing this (which is currentMillis)